# Song near the end of episode 18 of Parasyte when Uragami asks the detective to tell Izumi to look him in the eyes

Tags: music, parasyte

What is the name of the song played in episode 18 of *Parasyte* near the end when Uragami asks the detective to tell Izumi to look him in the eyes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. The song is called *Creep*.

Its OST number 10 of Special Soundtrack of *Parasyte-The Maxim* by Ken Arai.

Link to the song-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Veuz0fBnn4s

Comment: Good to hear that you found the song!
Could you maybe elaborate a bit more on which _creep_ it is? Maybe from which artist, or in which ost it is included, if any. 
This will make it a lot easier for other people whom are also looking for it, to find it in the future.